# How to check the minimum length ion-textarea

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How do I validate the minimum length of a textarea in Ionic 3? Maxlength works great but strange that minLength does not work.

```
  <ion-textarea id="emailBody" minlength="2"  rows="3" required maxLength="500"  type="text" [(ngModel)]="emailBody"></ion-textarea>
```

Comment: do you mean content length? Those attributes dont seem to be [documented](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/#input-properties). Perhaps try to check the value length on change?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this solution

> ts file code

```
formObj:any={
        emailBody:""
}
```

> html file code

```
<ion-textarea  minlength="2"  rows="3" required maxLength="500"  type="text" [(ngModel)]="formObj.emailBody" #emailBody="ngModel"></ion-textarea>


<div *ngIf="emailBody.invalid && (emailBody.dirty || emailBody.touched)"
     class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="emailBody.errors.required">
    emailBody is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="emailBody.errors.minlength">
    emailBody must be at least 2 characters long.
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used some of Krishna Rathore and some of what I found.

Thanks for the push in right direction.

```
  <div class="padding-left-right-10"  *ngIf="!passedEmailTextCheck">
    email text is required.
  </div>
```

ts file

```
if (!passedEmailText) {
   this.passedEmailTextCheck = false;
} else {
```

// javascript value check

```
if( value ) {
}
will evaluate to true if value is not:

null
undefined
NaN
empty string ''
0
false
typescript includes javascript rules.
```

Answer (score -1):

capture the input event on the control and see for the length

```
<ion-textarea id="emailBody" minlength="2"  rows="3" required maxLength="500"  type="text" [(ngModel)]="emailBody" (input)="checkLength($event.target.value)"></ion-textarea>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
checkLength(value:any){
   if(value.length<=2){
      //min length found. 
   }
};
```